# How come dots/navigation buttons are not visiable using owlcarousel?

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

How come the navigation buttons are not visible?

I'm using `jQuery` and `owlcarousel` (http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/).

http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/s10bgckL/1/

[image: screenshot]

`html` ..

```
<div id="owl-demo">
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Owl Image" />
    </div>
</div>
```

`js` ..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

        autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
        dots: true,
        items: 2,
        itemsDesktop: [1199, 3],
        itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 3]
    });
});
```

`css` ..

```
#owl-demo .item {
    margin: 3px;
}
#owl-demo .item img {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: how did you resolved this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340868/owl-carousel-2-pagination-dots-were-not-diplayed

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The minified css file you have doesn't appear to have a style for that element: `.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page span`.

Here are the styles that are applied by the demo on the owlgraphic.com site:
http://jsfiddle.net/s10bgckL/2/

Comment: If I change your code to say - dots: false, the dots still appear!

Comment: @Neil: I just used the ops jsfiddle.  I only updated it to include the correct stylesheet.  It indeed appears that the `dots` option does nothing.

Comment: I just checked the docs, it seems the property is pagination: false to turn off the dots.

Comment: i am facing the issue, can you please help me know to resolve the issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340868/owl-carousel-2-pagination-dots-were-not-diplayed

Answer (score 9):

```
pagination:false,
navigation:true
```

try this

Answer (score 4):

Add CSS for Owl Carousel theme,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css" />
```

and change,

```
<div id="owl-demo">
```

to

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-theme">
```

Demo: [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/more89aniket/3dvwf40k/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you are running into is you didn't include the Owl Carousel theme. Not sure if you are using the CDN, but look here: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/owl-carousel and make sure you include the CSS for the theme in addition to the standard CSS.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set this particular option `dots:true`

```
$('.banner .owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items:1,
    loop:true,
    dots:true,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:7000,
    autoplayHoverPause:false,
    navText : ["<i class='fa fa-long-arrow-left'></i>","<i class='fa fa-long-arrow-right'></i>"]
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Go to **owl.carousel.min.js** or **owl.carousel.js** file whatever you linked.

Find and Replace `disabled` with `anyClass`. You'll Find 6 times, enjoy!