# owlcarousel - dots do not appear

Tags: javascript, css, owl-carousel

I am working on a project and as my knowledge in javascript are very limited, I decided to use `owlcarousel`. everything was working fine but now I am facing a problem.

I have set the dots to true but they do not appear. My work so far is the following:

```css
.container {
 width: 90%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

/*Text over image*/
.item {
 width: 100%;
}

.item img {
   display: block;
   max-width:100%;
}


/*Carousel Nav Buttons*/

.carousel-nav-left{
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    margin: auto 0;
    margin-left: -40px;
}

.carousel-nav-right{
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
 right: 0%;
    margin: auto 0;
    margin-right: -40px;
}


@media (max-width: 700px) {
 
 .carousel-nav-left{
  margin-left: -30px;
 }

 .carousel-nav-right{
  margin-right: -30px;
 }
 
 .container {
  width: 85%;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 410px) {
 
 .carousel-nav-left{
  margin-left: -25px;
 }

 .carousel-nav-right{
  margin-right: -25px;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>owlcarousel</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
 
    <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="carousel">
   
    <div class="item">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250"  alt="" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250"  alt="" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250"  alt="" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250"  alt="" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250"  alt="" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
     <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250"  alt="" />
    </div>
    
   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   (function($){
 
    $('.carousel').owlCarousel({
     items: 4,
     loop:true,
     margin:10,
     nav:true,
     navText: ["<span class='carousel-nav-left'><i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i></span>","<span class='carousel-nav-right'><i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i></span>"],
     dots: true,
     paginationSpeed: 300,
     rewindSpeed: 400,
     responsive:{
      0:{
       items:1
      },
      490:{
       items:2
      },
      770:{
       items:3
      },
      1200:{
       items:4
      },
      1500:{
       items:5
      }
     }
    })
    
   })(jQuery);
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Please let me know how I can fix this issue

Comment: Hi, is this live somewhere? A link would really help us to investigate. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How come dots/navigation buttons are not visiable using owlcarousel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405929/how-come-dots-navigation-buttons-are-not-visiable-using-owlcarousel)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ensure that you have included all of the necessary resources:

- jquery-2.1.1.min.js
- owl.carousel.min.js
- owl.carousel.min.css

Also, make sure your CSS includes the appropriate owl-page and owl-controls

Here is one example of vital CSS code:

```
.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page {
    display: inline-block;
}
.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page span {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #869791;
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: block;
    height: 12px;
    margin: 5px 7px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 12px;
}
```

As seen in [This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s10bgckL/2/).

Note that if you remove the `dots: true` from the JSFiddle code (and run it) the pagination "dots" still display. However, if you remove the above CSS, the dots do not display.

---

**Additional Answer**

*As this is the accepted answer I will add another potential fix as provided by @Kevin Vincendeau and brought to attention by @Amr Ibrahim in the comments.*

Check to make sure your HTML is including all of the necessary classes. Such as `owl-carousel` and `owl-theme` on the main container.

Comment: Please check the other answers and add this part .
` Classes owl-carousel and owl-theme on main container are necessary for the dots to appear. `

Answer (score 67):

I also faced the same problem while using Owl slider for the first time on my webpage. I could not see the dots navigation and I thought to myself this may be a bug and decided to do some investigation.

I figured later that there are 2 css files required to be included. One is the `own-carousel.min.css` and the other is `owl.theme.default.min.css`. After this the container div should have the `owl-carousel` and `owl-theme` class in their class list. For e.g:

```
<div id="slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <img src="/dist/assets/img1.jpg" /> 
        <img src="/dist/assets/img2.jpg" /> 
        <img src="/dist/assets/img3.jpg" /> 
        <img src="/dist/assets/img4.jpg" />
</div>
```

Hope this helps for people who are facing this issue later.

Answer (score 28):

Classes `owl-carousel` and `owl-theme` on main container are necessary for the dots to appear.

Answer (score 12):

> **The point was the lack of the `owl-theme` class in your code!**

**Include CSS & JS resources**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

**Set up your HTML**

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div> Content 1 </div>
  <div> Content 2</div>
  <div> Content 3</div>
  <div> Content 4</div>
  <div> Content 5</div>
  <div> Content 6</div>
  <div> Content 7</div>
</div>
```

> **Note:** if you dose not include the `owl-theme` class in the parent `Div` then the Dots dose not appear to you. So it is necessary to make them visible to end
>   users.

**Call the plugin**

Now call the Owl initializer function and your carousel is ready.

```
$(function(){
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
});
```

**Demo:**

[image]

```js
$(function(){
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();        
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    
<!-- Set up your HTML -->
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div> Content 1 </div>
  <div> Content 2</div>
  <div> Content 3</div>
  <div> Content 4</div>
  <div> Content 5</div>
  <div> Content 6</div>
  <div> Content 7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the **Owl Carousel dots will only show up when you have enough items**.

Forexample, if you show 3 items at the same time, the dots will only show up if there is 4 or more items in that carousel.

Answer (score 1):

Adding css worked for me!

```
    .owl-dots .owl-dot span {
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        margin: 5px 7px;
        background: #D6D6D6;
        display: block;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
        transition: opacity .2s ease;
        border-radius: 30px;
    }
    
    .owl-dots .owl-dot.active span, .owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot:hover span {
        background: #869791;
    }
```

Comment: Yes! that code solved my problem!
Also you need to add:

.owl-dots{display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;margin-top: 10px;}

Answer (score 0):

According to Owl Carousel docs, you have to call the 2 **CSS** files below (inside **head tag**):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.theme.default.min.css">
```

then near to **footer tag**, call JQuery and Owl Carousel JS scripts:

```html
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

I was facing the same issue on my code, then i just empty all owl and jquery files, read the owl docs, following the installation process step by step. Now it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();        
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    
<!-- Set up your HTML -->
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div> Content 1 </div>
  <div> Content 2</div>
  <div> Content 3</div>
  <div> Content 4</div>
  <div> Content 5</div>
  <div> Content 6</div>
  <div> Content 7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            loop: true,
            autoplayTimeout: 2000,
            autoplayHoverPause: true,
            dots: false,
            margin: 5,
            nav: true,
            responsive: {
                0: {
                    items: 1
                },
                600: {
                    items: 3
                },
                1000: {
                    items: 4
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

> Try : dots: false,