# Owl Carousel 2 pagination dots were not diplayed

Tags: html, css, angularjs, carousel, owl-carousel

I am experiencing issue. The navigation components owl-nav and owl-dots are no longer wrapped with owl-controls.

```
<div class="owl-nav disabled">
  <div class="owl-prev">prev</div>
  <div class="owl-next">next</div>
</div>
<div class="owl-dots disabled">
  <div class="owl-dot active"><span></span></div>
  <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
</div>
```

Demos show:

```
<div class="owl-controls">
  <div class="owl-nav disabled">
    <div class="owl-prev">prev</div>
    <div class="owl-next">next</div>
  </div>
  <div class="owl-dots disabled">
    <div class="owl-dot active"><span></span></div>
    <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is breaking the default css selections within owl-theme.

Can any one help me to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not true, you can see it on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JSDavi/w3ka3vqw/). You can even change class names, or set your own container via options.

Comment: This is in my case the pagination buttons were not displayed.

Comment: The problem is not the Carousel 2, if you can show us real page with issue, than maybe we could help.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, used some CSS-Styling my own:

```
 .owl-dots {
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.owl-dot {
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(127,127,127, 0.5);
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.owl-dot.active {
    background: rgba(127,127,127, 1);
}
```

If you don't want to overlaps the dots just use:

```
.owl-dots {
    text-align: center;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to add owl-theme file also to get pagination dots.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#demoCarousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    dots: true // if you don't want dots, change to false
  });
});
```

```css
#demoCarousel .item {
  height: 10rem;
  background: #4DC7A0;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="demoCarousel">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue, Add more slides and dots will appear.